# group by issue in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

i'm trying to get in a new column the sessions who are between 08:00 and 18:00. You can see my last CASE in the CTE. For each date there should be a new column "TotalRestrictedSessions" which indicate how many session were on that particular date. If there are none, in this case i have to write 0. I suspect that my problem is when i convert the DATE?

```
WITH ParkeonCTE
AS
(
SELECT 
    OccDate = CONVERT(DATE, OC.LocalStartTime),
    TotalOccSessions = COUNT(OC.SessionId),
    AuthorityId,
    TotalOccDuration = ISNULL(SUM(OC.DurationMinutes),0),
    TotalNumberOfOverstay = SUM(CAST(OC.IsOverstay AS INT)),
    TotalMinOfOverstays = ISNULL(SUM(OC.OverStayDurationMinutes),0),
    (CASE
        WHEN OC.OspId IS NULL THEN 'OffStreet' ELSE 'OnStreet'
        END
    ) AS ParkingContextType,
    (CASE
        WHEN CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) >= '08:00:00' AND CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) <= 
 '18:00:00'
            THEN COUNT(OC.SessionId)
     END
    ) AS TotalRestrictedSessions
FROM Analytics.OccupancySessions AS OC
WHERE OC.AuthorityId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATE,OC.LocalStartTime), OC.AuthorityId,OC.OspId
)
SELECT OC.OccDate,
   OC.ParkingContextType,
   OC.AuthorityId,
   OC.TotalRestrictedSessions,
   SUM(OC.TotalOccSessions) AS TotalOccSessions,
   AVG(OC.TotalOccDuration) AS AvgOccMinutesDuration, -- wrong
   SUM(OC.TotalOccDuration) AS TotalOccDuration,
   SUM(OC.TotalNumberOfOverstay) AS TotalNumberOfOverstay,
   SUM(OC.TotalMinOfOverstays) AS TotalMinOfOverstays,
   CAST(AVG(OC.TotalMinOfOverstays) AS decimal(10,2)) AS AvgMinOfOverstays -- wrong
  FROM ParkeonCTE AS OC
GROUP BY OC.OccDate, OC.AuthorityId, OC.ParkingContextType
ORDER BY OC.OccDate DESC
```

Comment: What's the problem though? Not knowing what the problem is I'm just guessing that maybe `SUM(CASE
        WHEN CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) >= '08:00:00' AND CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) <= 
 '18:00:00'
            THEN 1 Else 0
     END
    ) AS TotalRestrictedSessions` might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move your aggregation outside of your `CASE` expression, called conditional aggregation.

```
  SUM(CASE
        WHEN CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) >= '08:00:00' 
        AND CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) <= '18:00:00'
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS TotalRestrictedSessions
```

Generally, you should include the current query results and your desired results in your question to make it easier to figure out where the issues are.

Comment: Thanks, Eric - I understand now. This solved the problem now, I guess. I have to check the data to make sure :). My question would be, if I cast the DateTime as time, my approach to filtering by a specific time, it is correct?

Comment: That broader question is hard to answer without sample data to work with. I'd suggest you start by taking a small subset enough subset of your data that you can see what the results should be, then run your query against that and see if it returns what you're expecting. If not, post a new question that includes your sample data, the results you get, and a mock up of the results you would expect.